# Grammar parsing

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Could anybody parse these words, please, because I am not sure I get all the subtleties. I am intereseted not in their semantics, but rather sentence syntax.

> On which soil we stand on, that is where we carry the weight of the
>   sky

Comment: That is not a grammatically valid sentence in Standard English. What is the source? Is there some context?

Comment: It's a proverb.
Sources: http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/source/m/malay_proverb/92539.htm
http://www.listofproverbs.com/keywords/weight/

No context. I just run across it while surfing.

Answer (score 2):

The second *on* should be omitted.

Comment: (Original q now amended.)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the English versions of other Malay proverbs at the link OP provided, this is not the only poor translation. I don't know the original, but would imagine it means something like:

> On whichever soil we stand, that is where we carry the weight of the
>   sky.

If this is the case, then *On whichever soil we stand* is the subordinate or dependent clause (in this case an adverb clause), and *that is where we carry the weight of the sky* is the main or independent clause

Comment: And how this constraction (on whichever...that is) can be paraphrased? Does it mean: "we carry the of the sky on whichever soil we stand"?

Comment: Yes, that is how I interpret it: _Wherever we are, we will still have to deal with the problems life throws at us_. It would be good if a Malay speaker could confirm that my rephrasing is indeed a correct translation, and that the interpretation is also correct.